# How do you determine when to use certain test statistics?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, inference, t-distribution

I've been trying to formulate this question and have struggled, so if it seems ill-worded, I apologize:

A statistics book I have has a table in the back that says:

- For an inference test regarding a proportion, generally a z-test is
  used.
- For an inference test regarding a mean, a t-test is generally used.
- For an inference test regarding “goodness of fit”, a chi-square test
  is generally used.
- For an inference test regarding association between two quantitative
  variables, a t-test is used.

How are these decisions made? How can I know that a “goodness of fit” test statistic is optimally calculated by a chi-square statistic, etc.

Additionally, how is it that the normal distribution somehow fits the proportion (z) statistic, but not a t-distribution, or chi-square distribution, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Good question, but I fear it's rather broad for this site, as the usual answer spans a chapter or several in books introducing statistical theory.

Comment: @Scortchi I see. Any good references to start?

Comment: See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/581049/805